# How display several Vaadin properties in a single table cell?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have 3 properties of a java class which I require to display
below each other in a table cell.

The 3 properties are added to a container which is bound to a table -
however, this leads to each property occupying a different cell in
the same row.

```
e.g.
Container container = new IndexedContainer();
container.addContainerProperty("property1", String.class, "dftvalue1");
container.addContainerProperty("property2", String.class, "dftvalue2");
container.addContainerProperty("property3", String.class, "dftvalue3");

container.getContainerProperty(itemId, "property1").setValue("value1");
...
Table table = new Table("My Table");
table.setContainerDataSource(container);
```

I require to display as below.

---

```
          |  property1   |
col1      |  property2   |
          |  property3   |
```

---

Please can you inform/advise how this can be done?
Thank you Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would implement a [`Table.ColumnGenerator`](https://vaadin.com/api/7.4.0/com/vaadin/ui/Table.ColumnGenerator.html#generateCell%28com.vaadin.ui.Table,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) for this.  Then create the
content for the cell there.  The content can be "any" vaadin `Component`.

Either use e.g. `Label` with HTML content and
concat your props with `<br/>` (be aware of XSS!).  Or you can also create a
vertical layout and add a label for each property.

Something like this:

```
def c = new BeanItemContainer<SomeBean>(SomeBean)
c.addAll([
        new SomeBean(prop1: "prop11", prop2: "prop12", prop3: "prop13"),
        new SomeBean(prop1: "prop21", prop2: "prop22", prop3: "prop23"),
        new SomeBean(prop1: "prop31", prop2: "prop32", prop3: "prop33"),
])
setContent(new Table().with{
    setContainerDataSource(c, [])
    addGeneratedColumn("combined", {Table source, Object itemId, Object columnId ->
        (source.getItem(itemId) as BeanItem<SomeBean>).bean.with{
            // UNSAFE CODE! DON'T USE VERBATIM
            new Label("$it.prop1<br />$it.prop2<br />$it.prop3", ContentMode.HTML)
        }
    })
    setVisibleColumns(["combined"].toArray())
    it
})
```